# How to use AWS iOS SDK to listen to an S3 bucket an download a file once it gets put there

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I'm writing an iOS app that is using the AWS SDK to upload and download files from an S3 bucket. Some data will be processed on EC2 and it will place a file into S3 after an unknown amount of time, so I want to have my app listen to the S3 bucket and automatically download a file with a particular name once it gets created. I've been looking through the AWS iOS API and haven't been able to find any listeners of the type I'm looking for. I also feel like AWS Lambda may be helpful here but all I've seen is about a mobile app triggering a Lambda function, not receiving a message from one. Any idea how I should go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Amazon EC2 instance is putting a file to an Amazon S3 bucket, it can also send a push notification to your device using [Amazon SNS Mobile Push Notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html). You can set up an [AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) function on the S3 bucket to push the notification as well. The device then should pull the file from the S3 bucket.

Comment: Would this push notification be similar to what I would get from say, a text message? I'm looking for this all to happen in the background without the user probably even realizing it.

Comment: You can do a silent push notification by modifying `Info.plist`. See [The Remote Notification Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html) for more details (probably, `content-available` is what you are looking for).